# How to create a GraphQL Interface on AWS Amplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

How would I go about creating an Event Interface on AWS Amplify where there are different types of Events like in the documentation example? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/interfaces-and-unions.html

The documentation does a good job confirming that GraphQL Interfaces exist (as does the official GraphQL documentation) but I can't find a single article or example of how to implement it on AWS Amplify. Surely it's common to have such types? What are other people doing in these situations?

I've posted an issue on the support repo but not sure if I'll get an answer. If I do I'll update this post. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-adminui/issues/140

**Update:** There is an answer on that GitHub issue but I've since abandoned AWS Amplify since they don't support Kotlin Multiplatform.